# Why aren't all languages showing up in Github Repo?

Tags: github

I'm about to submit this project but I want to make sure the Github page looks good before I do. For some reason, not all the languages are showing up and I don't know why. I've tried to find ways to edit this under settings but I've yet to find anything.

As you see in the images below, on the homepage it says the Repo is 100% Jupyter notebooks, but if you click on "languages" you'll see that there are python and csv files as well that seem to be unaccounted for.

[image]

[image]

If anyone knows how I can change this please let me know. It's not very important but I think it'd look much nicer if the breakdown of languages was more accurate. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GitHub uses [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) to figure out which languages are part of your project. It has a [`languages.yml`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml) file to defined the multitude of languages to look for. Some are markup languages (like `jupyter notebook`), some programming languages, etc.

That percentage you see is calculated based on the bytes of code for each language. The more you have of one type, the higher the percentage.

**Note**, however, that this library **excludes** all files that it determines to be binary data, vendor code, generated code, documentation, or defined as data (in your case `csv`) or prose (think `markdown`), whilst taking into account any overrides.

**IF** your `python` code is small enough, even in 2 files, it won't get show up. Just write more python if you want it to show up.

---

The second screenshot provided is when you click on the languages and it's purpose is exactly what you are looking for - to give *better* details on the current project and what *it* comprises of in *detail*. This language bar is just an overview. It need not be 100% accurate.

FIY - It also matters which is your main branch, since it takes that into account.

---

Conclusion - don't worry about it. Whoever needs to see it, will see what your project has in terms of contents.

Comment: Is it possible to override these and display all languages?

Comment: @DaCuteRaccoon I haven't looked into it too much but maybe this section on [`overrides`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md) looks helpful for your question :)